# Does Neovim or any of its GUI variants have the option to be embedded in a Window?

Tags: emacs, embedded, neovim

Emacs as the ability to be embedded in a GUI window using the `--parent-id=xid` option which is an X Window handle.

So I have created GUI programs in which can embed an Emacs session for improved editing.

Does Neovim or its variants have similar options?